# YAML syntax error (Ansible playboook)

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to write a playbook that installs Apache, but I get the below error:

```
The offending line appears to be:

tasks:
     - name: command to install apache
       ^ here
```

Here is my YAML code:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
     - name: command to install apache
       sudo: yes
       yum: name=httpd state=latest
       service: name=httpd state=running
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add two actions (modules) to a single task in Ansible.

You need to split `yum` and `service` into two tasks.

Also `sudo` declaration was deprecated long time ago and now `become` should be used:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Ensure apache is installed
      become: yes
      yum: name=httpd state=latest

    - name: Ensure httpd service is running
      become: yes
      service: name=httpd state=running
```

Answer (score 0):

value of state must be one of: reloaded, restarted, started, stopped.

- name: Ensure httpd service is started
  become: yes
  service: name=httpd state=started